# "prepend" a CSS transform

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, matrix-multiplication, css-transforms

Considering this element:

```
<div style="transform:rotate(9deg) scale(3) translate(20px,10%) skew(-11deg)"></div>
```

I'd like to add another transformation `translate(5px)` but **before all others** (ie: "prepend"):

```
<div style="transform: rotate(9deg) scale(3) translate(20px,10%) skew(-11deg)"></div>
                      ^
                 translate(5px)
```

How can I script this with javascript/jQuery?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol, well I thought it was, until I realized `$(el).css('transform')` returned a `'matrix(,,,,,)'` or `'matrix3d(,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,)'` string :)

Comment: You can still prepend a new transform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, even though the style is originally declared by individual transforms, when you retrieve the transform thru javascript, you get a matrix.

No problem, just set the transform with the matrix

```
<div style="transform: translateX(5px) matrix(values get from javascript)">
```

Comment: "But you spell *through* T-H-R-U and I'm with you on that, because we spell it *th-rough*, and that's just trying to cheat at Scrabble..."

Comment: Can't argue with an english man about spelling, but just to somehow justify my spelling, take a look here http://grammar.about.com/od/spelling/a/The-Futility-Of-Spelling-Reform.htm